# Top 10 Subquery in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT TOP 10 [FINAL_FOR_DB].[Indemnity_Paid]/[FINAL_FOR_DB].[Claim_Count] AS Indemnity_Cost, 
final_for_db.Claimant_Name, 
final_for_db.Account_Name, 
final_for_db.Claim_ID, 
final_for_db.File_Date, 
final_for_db.Resolution_Date, 
final_for_db.Claim_Status, 
final_for_db.State_Filed, final_for_db.Expense_Amount, 
final_for_db.Claim_Count, 
final_for_db.Indemnity_Paid AS [Total Indemnity]
FROM final_for_db
WHERE (((final_for_db.Account_Name)="Exxon"))
ORDER BY [FINAL_FOR_DB].[Indemnity_Paid]/[FINAL_FOR_DB].[Claim_Count] DESC;
```

This would only give me top 10 entries for Exxon but I am wondering if there is a way to get top 10 entries for each account name from the biggest indemnity cost to the lowest. I believe there is a need for subquery. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: what dbserver miseur ? Probably Mr. Softie

Comment: Access, Mysql, and Sql-Server are three very different RDBMS's. If you are using "Access" then please lose the Mysql and sql-server tags.

Comment: @JNEvill i was referring to Access. My Bad

Answer (score 0):

Other RDBMS's support the RANK() and ROW_NUMBER() functions.  Unfortunately, Access does not (to my knowledge).  This should get you close to what you want.  It does not handle duplicates well (two customers with the same indemnity cost would get the same rank, possibly leaving you with the top 11 or so).

```
Select * From 
(
    Select *
        , (
            Select count(*) 
            From final_for_db as tbl2
            where (tbl1.Indemnity_Paid/tbl1.Claim_Count) < (tbl2.Indemnity_Paid/tbl2.Claim_Count)
                and tbl1.Account_Name= tbl2.Account_Name
        ) + 1 as rank from final_for_db tbl1
) x where x.Rank < 10
```

Comment: Try running it now; I cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: @StevenR it says invalid argument function